# Image is a little larger after rotating with jQueryRotate

Tags: jquery, rotation

I have tried using both [jQueryRotate v2.0](http://plugins2.jquery.com/content/jqueryrotate-20) and v1.7. But in both cases the image is little larger after rotation.  How can I solve this problem? 
I'm rotating with the following code:

```
var test = 0;
$('#working-area .rotatable').live('click', function(event) {
    test = test + 90;
    $(this).rotate({
        angle: test,
        containment: "working-area"
    });
});
```

Comment: can you give link to your site again?

Comment: You will only get an answer if you show some effort on your side. Please start by posting your code.

Comment: this is my site [link](http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50)

Comment: where do you rotate. The grid is too intense, makes your eyes hurt.

Comment: @Hussein I need those grid. and my problem is when I rotate the image after drop it on grid the image will little larger than its original size.

Comment: I am having difficulty finding image. on click, the image is turned into `.rotable` span with `<canvas>` element. And it is also not working properly, on few clicks, image vanishes. My suggestion, use flash or applet than javascript. JavaScript can be buggy.

Comment: @experimentX on single click it will rotate and on double click the image will hide. I need this only with javascript. is any other option to edit that jquery plugin?

Comment: @Moumita lets see, will check

Answer (score 3):

The image will surely take up larger space when it rotates especially if the image is a rectangle because the height and the width are of different sizes. Take a 8x4 piece of paper, for example, rotate it 45 degrees sideways. You will find that the paper now takes up half of its former height and double its former width. Now rotate it 22.5 degrees more and you will find that the height is now 3/4 larger.

The usual solution is to make a square dimension containment with the height or width of the image, whichever is higher, then add a quarter to that value to accommodate the change in dimension when rotating.

Comment: my image is a straight line and always rotate 90 degree angle.

Comment: Can we take a look at your page?

Comment: sure this is my site [link](http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50)

Comment: @Moumita, I tested your page and I didn't see any change in size of the objects inside the working area using the grid as measuring guide.

Comment: yes using the grid as measuring guide there is no change but if you see the image it look like thin and long than the original image.

Answer (score 1):

When you create image `<img src="images/tool_box/1.png" class="rotatable">` this is what you get.

When you click on image, you get

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 97px; height: 11px;" id="" class="rotatable">
    <canvas width="97" style="position: relative; left: -0.310859px; top: -43.3109px;" height="97"></canvas>
</span>
```

Certainly this plugin is doing this. I can't help you. I suggest you to make your own function and do rotation.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var imgcss = {"-webkit-transform":"rotate(-90deg)", "-moz-transform" : "rotate(-90deg)" };
    var imgcss1 = {"-webkit-transform":"rotate(0deg)", "-moz-transform" : "rotate(0deg)" };

    var flag = false;

    $(function ()
    {
        $('#img').live('click', function(event) {           
            if(flag == false){
                $(this).css(imgcss);
                flag = true;
            }
            else{
                $(this).css(imgcss1);
                flag = false;
            }
    });
    })
</script>
<div id="working-area">
    <img src="img.jpg" id="img"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and time. I will try it with this code.thanks once again.

Comment: @Moumita abt your new question, i think you should ask pretty basic question like ...how to create image from html page using javascript. Anyway, you also can get live help from chat@javascript.

Comment: is it chat from stackoverflow site. should  I enter to the chat room?

Comment: @Moumita yes ... it's on the top of the page or click http://chat.stackoverflow.com/